# check top 100 domains in email list

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have a large email list, and i want to know what is the top 100 domains on this list, example list :

```
cristiano.ofidiani@libero.it
cristianocurzi70@libero.it
cristianogiustetto@libero.it
cristianopaolieri@fercart.com
cristianoristori@tiscali.it
cristianorollo@tiscali.it
cristianoscavi@alice.it
cristianotradigo@virgilio.it
cristianpassarelli@virgilio.it
cristianprisco@libero.it
cristianriparip@riparifranco.it
cristiansrl.pec@legalmail.it
cristina.arese@vestisolidale.it
cristina.armillotta@coldiretti.it
cristina.bazzi@bazzicroup.it
cristina.bedocchi@tin.it
cristina.benassi@terminalrubiero.com
```

i need to know the top of domains in this list, example :

```
libero.it 100
tiscali.it 77
legalmain 44
```

how i can do this in linux bash ?

Comment: Check the man pages for `cut`, `sort` and `uniq`

Comment: @Makoto There's no tricky `bash` syntax necessary here; @hhoke1's answer shows a straightforward pipeline of 54 characters. The shortest reasonable Python command for this is something like `print(Counter(x.split("@")[1] for x in stdin).most_common(100))`, which ignores the `import`s necessary to use `Counter` and `stdin`. This is a task that the shell and some standard tools are well suited to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut -d@ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 100` should do the trick. Cut extracts the domain by using @ to separate the fields, uniq requires a sorted list, `-c` gives a count, `sort -nr` sorts them in decreasing order, and `head` gives the top one hundred.